# error: bad operand types for binary operator '||'

Tags: java

This is my statement

```
while(coord.getRow() || coord.getColumn() != 0)
```

I basically want it to loop while the x coordinate and y coordinates are not 0. then stop executing when either equals 0. Both the row and column of the object cord are ints.

Like the title I'm receiving the error:

```
error: bad operand types for binary operator '||'
```

I could I go about executing a while loop to do something like this?

Comment: What do you think the error means? And have you checked for a description of what `||` does?

Comment: Logical operators, such as OR (`||`), are binary expressions meaning they need a left **and** right hand value in order to be evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(coord.getRow() != 0 && coord.getColumn() != 0)
```

instead of

```
while(coord.getRow() || coord.getColumn() != 0)
```

Comment: I thought it was something as simple as that, my brains just a little fried at the moment. I appreciate the help, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
while((coord.getRow() != 0) && (coord.getColumn() != 0)) {
    // etc...
}
```

You have to use `&&` here instead of `||`, because you want to stop when *either* equals 0, so in your while case you have to make sure *both* are not zero.

The reason for the error is that logical operators like `||` and `&&` in Java expect logical expressions. In other words, something that can evaluate to true or false.

Since your functions return integers, these are not logically valid. Whereas, something like `coord.getRow() != 0` is either true or false depending on what `coord.getRow()` is.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
while(coord.getRow() != 0 && coord.getColumn() != 0)
```

use  `&&` (and) operator instead of `||` (or).

`&&` is true if both true on the other hand `||` is true if any one is true.